# dir() can't work in list comprehension

Tags: python

When I check whether the `expanduser` function belongs to the `sys` module or to the `os` module,I code this:

```
>>> [m for m in dir(os.path.__all__) if m.startswith('ex')]
['extend']
```

Obviously,it can't filter `expanduser`. So I code and it works for me:

```
>>> [m for m in os.path.__all__ if m.startswith('ex')]
['exists', 'expanduser', 'expandvars', 'extsep']
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Did you mean `dir(os.path)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__all__` is a list inside `os.path` submodule's `__init__.py` file. It is not the same as calling `dir` on the actual submodule.

You'll need `dir(os.path)` instead, to examine its actual contents.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `dir` on `os.path` directly, not on the `__all__` attribute which is a list whose `dir` leaves you with the attributes of a list:

```
>>> [m for m in dir(os.path) if m.startswith('ex')]
['exists', 'expanduser', 'expandvars', 'extsep']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a list to `dir` when you call:

```
dir(os.path.__all__)
```

because `os.path.__all__` is a list of strings.  This is the same as calling

```
dir([])
```

You need to call:

```
dir(os.path)
```

instead.